# Trying to use a script to shutdown my Synology Linux NAS from windows Using PLINK

Tags: linux

I am trying to create a script that logs into the Synology NAS using plink and runs shutdown -h now so I can shut it down b4 my UPC loses power in the event of a power outage.  I had it working before but can’t remember how, but pretty much I have it setup to login using plink and use a ssh key which works, but then when it runs the -bash sudo shutdown -h now it wants a password.  I don’t want to pass a password for security reasons if possible.  Any ideas on how to get this to work?  I’ve tried to play with the sudoers file and tell the user to have access to nopasswd but it doesn’t work.